# Is it possible to use Textbox and Combobox at the same time with JOptionPane?

Tags: java

As the title says, I have this homework where I need to make a user input where the user will write his email, the teacher wants it to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtXnG.png

Is it possible to do it with JOptionPane? Or is it more complex than that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the base JOptionPane will work. The closest thing it looks like you have to use to your screenshot is [JOptionPane#showInputDialog(Component, Object, String, int, Icon, Object[], Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))

You will probably want to create your own `Component`. Maybe an extension of JOptionPane to allow multiple inputs but since you said this is for a homework assignment, I'm going to leave that to you to figure out.

EDIT: I stand corrected. JOptionPane can be used for this task, but won't display like the screenshot. Note that the `message` parameter in the `showInputDialog` function is an Object...hint hint...try playing with that. Again, I won't provide code snippets since this is a HW assignment, but I will point you in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm looking into it now :)

Comment: I updated my answer, I was semi-mistaken...you can have the functionality you want in `JOptionPane`, but it will not display the same way as in the screenshot. If the display is a requirement, then you will still need to build your own `Component`, but if not then you can use it.